# Osmdroid - change the default (white) color of the direction arrow (or how to customize the icon)

Tags: android, osmdroid

After upgrading from osmdroid:6.03, mapsforge 0.8, osmbonuspack 6.4 to the newest versions, I can work with both the v4 and v5 Mapsforge maps. **Thank you** so much for thes great libraries I use for 6 years!

Everything is working fine. When not moving the yellow man is drawn, but when moving the direction arrow turns out to be **WHITE**. When moving I can see that the center of the map is redrawn and thus changing. How can I change the arrow back to a more visible arrow?

[image]

These are the versions of the libraries:

```
implementation 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.6.0'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.6'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.1.6'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.11.0'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:0.11.0'
```

When starting to navigate, I use within a Fragment:

```
gpsLocationProvider = new GpsMyLocationProvider( this.getContext());
gpsLocationProvider.setLocationUpdateMinTime( GPS.GPS_ACCURACY_HIGH_TIME);
gpsLocationProvider.setLocationUpdateMinDistance( GPS.GPS_ACCURACY_HIGH_DISTANCE);

myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay( mv);
myLocationOverlay.setDrawAccuracyEnabled( false); 
myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation( gpsLocationProvider);
mv.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);

myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final GeoPoint myLocation = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
        if (myLocation != null) {
            getMyActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mv.getController().animateTo(myLocation);
                    mv.getController().animateTo( myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
                    currentLocation = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
                }
            });
        };
    }
});
```

How can I turn the direction arrow back to a visible one? White is not easy to distinguish ;-)

Notice: I can see that the center of the map is moving when I move around. The 'runOnUiThread' lines are used for working within a Fragment. Without these lines I get errors for drawing not on the Looper/main threa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About 1.5 years ago the standard yellow man (current position) and green direction arrow were removed from the Osmdroid package. They changed this icon because they only had one dpi version and not having a version for each dpi folder (h,m,xh,xxh,xxxh).

So, you have to add your own version. Advised was to take from material.io the two-tone "navigation" 48 version for the direction arrow. When you change the direction arrow, as shown below, you also need to provide an icon for the current location.

After retrieving those items, I converted them to bitmaps. You can use online tools for that like www.online-convert.com.

Finally you can add the following code to your app:

```
Bitmap bitmapNotMoving = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.twotone_insert_emoticon_black_48dp);
Bitmap bitmapMoving = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.twotone_navigation_black_48);
myLocationOverlay.setDirectionArrow( bitmapNotMoving, bitmapMoving);
```

The direction arrow centers nicely at the 'real' position.

Thank you developer monsieurtanuki from Osmdroid!